# Как сделать вывод из sql?

Tags: php, sql

Есть 3 таблицы,

1. Вывести 10 последних комментариев из базы и вывести информацию о авторе.
2. Вывести 5 последних ответов на комментарий из базы и вывести информацию о авторе.

Таблица комментариев

`comment_table`

1. `post_id` - ид поста
2. `post_news_id` - ид новости где оставлен комментарий
3. `post_autor_id` - ид автора комментария
4. `post_text` - текст комментария
5. `post_type` - тип комментария (1 - комментарий, 2 - ответ на комментарий)
6. `post_idcom` - если пост является ответом тогда тут ид на который комментарий был сделан ответ

Таблица юзеров

`user_table`

1. `uid` - ид юзера
2. `nikname` - никнейм
3. `avarar` - аватар

Все что я смог вывести это комментарий и инфа о авторе комментария `SELECT * FROM 
comment_table LEFT JOIN user_table ON comment_table.post_autor_id=user_table.uid WHERE post_news_id = '".$_GET[news_id]."' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 80`

Нужно, чтобы все это было в 1 запросе - не запросы в цикле.

Comment: Попробуйте более развернуто описать суть вопроса: как именно вы хотите увидеть результаты?
Также форматируйте код - так вам быстрее ответят.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть 3 таблицы
>
> comment_table
>
> user_table

Вы погнули мне мозг... Попробую предположить что нас интересуют только указанные 2 таблицы. Также предположу что вопросы я понял правильно (хотя уверенности нет, ибо вопрос задан очень уж своеобразно).

*" 1. Вывести 10 последних комментариев из базы и вывести информацию о авторе. "*
Просто 10 последних (по ID) записей из таблицы comment_table, являющихся комментариями а не ответом на комментарий + информация о авторах этих записей

```
SELECT
  ct.post_id,
  ct.post_news_id,
  ct.post_autor_id,
  ct.post_text,
  ct.post_type,
  ct.post_idcom,
  ut.uid,
  ut.nickname,
  ut.avatar
FROM
  comment_table ct
LEFT JOIN
  user_table ut ON ct.post_autor_id = ut.uid
WHERE
  ct.post_news_id = '".$_GET[news_id]."' and
  ct.post_type = 1
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

*" 2. Вывести 5 последних ответов на комментарий из базы и вывести информацию о авторе. "*
Сделал предположение что вас интересует какой-то конкретный комментарий и вы желаете увидеть ответы на этот комментарий. Запрос кардинально не поменяется, просто добавим в условие конкретный ID комментария на который мы будем смотреть ответы

```
SELECT
  ct.post_id,
  ct.post_news_id,
  ct.post_autor_id,
  ct.post_text,
  ct.post_type,
  ct.post_idcom,
  ut.uid,
  ut.nickname,
  ut.avatar
FROM
  comment_table ct
LEFT JOIN
  user_table ut ON ct.post_autor_id = ut.uid
WHERE
  ct.post_news_id = '".$_GET[news_id]."' and
  ct.post_type = 2 and
  ct.post_idcom = '".$_GET[main_post_id]."'
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Если же вас интересует комментарий + ответы на комментарий единой выборкой, то UNION ALL вам в руки.

Согласитесь, что код отформатированный таким образом читается гораздо лучше.

Comment: А если вам нужны выборки вида:
Комментарий1
-Ответ1_на_комментарий1
-Ответ2_на_комментарий1
- ...
-ОтветN_на_комментарий1
Комментарий2
-Ответ1_на_комментарий2
-Ответ2_на_комментарий2
- ...
-ОтветM_на_комментарий2
...
КомментарийX

То возможно вам придется познакомится с иерархическими (рекурсивными) запросами. А это уже решается с учетом СУБД которую вы используете.

В Oracle это будет конструкция connect by start with. В MSSQL по-моему подобных стандартный решений нет и там приходится реализовывать рекурсию, Но это уже совсем другой вопрос..

..мда короткие ответы это не моё...